# glob error <_io.TextIOWrapper name='...' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> reading text file error

Tags: python

I am trying to make a social program where the profiles are stored in .txt files
here is part of the code:

```
XX = []
pl = glob.glob('*.txt')
for a in pl:
     if ' pysocial profile.txt' in a:
         print(a)
         O = 2
         XX.append(a)
         if O == 2:
              P = input('choose profile>')
              if P in XX:
                G = open(P, 'r')
              print(G)
```

I try this, but when it executes the "print(G)" part it come out with this:

`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Freddie Taylor pysocial profile.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`.

How can I make it read the file?

Comment: I know the xx = [] is too far back so don't answer "format it properly!"

Comment: You know that the formatting is wrong and you don't correct it because you can't be bothered to present the information to the people trying to help you in readable form? What an attitude!

Answer (score 25):

The `open` method opens the file and returns a `TextIOWrapper` object but does not read the files content.

To actually get the content of the file, you need to call the `read` method on that object, like so:

```
G = open(P, 'r')
print(G.read())
```

However, you should take care of closing the file by either calling the `close` method on the file object or using the `with open(...)` syntax which will ensure the file is properly closed, like so:

```
with open(P, 'r') as G:
    print(G.read())
```