# Unexpected result when trying to open CSV file with Python3 using VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, visual-studio-code, python-import

I'm trying to open a csv file using Python (Python 3.9.0, in VS Code, MacOS), using `with open`. The basic code I have is as follows:

```
import csv
import os

file_to_load = os.path.join("resources","original_file.csv")
with open(file_to_load) as starting_numbers:
    print(starting_numbers)
```

The result I got was:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='resources/original_file.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

The result I expected was:

```
<open file 'Resources/original_file.csv', mode 'r' at 0x[memory address]>
```

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744244/glob-error-io-textiowrapper-name-mode-r-encoding-cp1252-reading-tex) from four years ago, but it doesn't seem to be directly related to my problem. I'm not currently trying to get a full readout of the file, just the memory allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<open file ...>` was the python 2 string representation of an open file. In python 3, file management was decomposed into layers to implement different bits of functionality. A text wrapper will decode the file's bytes into python 3's strings which are fully unicode enabled, while a binary file just needs a reader. See [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and [Text I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o).

```
>>> open('test.py')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='a.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> open('test.py', 'rb')
<_io.BufferedReader name='a.py'>
```

When opening a file in text mode, `TextIOWrapper` is layered on the binary `BufferedReader`

```
>>> f = open('test.py')
>>> f.buffer
<_io.BufferedReader name='test.py'>
```

Old examples written for python 2 don't necessarily mention that they are python 2 and you may need to "read the tea leaves" to figure it out. A file object looking like `<open file ...>` is a dead giveaway.

Comment: What I'm understanding from your answer is that there is nothing inherently wrong with my code, just with what I'm expecting. The expected result is what I would have received under Python 2.

Comment: Right. What you see is normal for python 3.

Comment: But wouldn't it be better, to open the file in "rt" mode? to explicitely open it as a text file? or does this mean that text is the default now?

Comment: I meant to add doc references, I'll put them in. "t" is now the default (which means its not needed at all) and you use "b" to do binary instead. In fact the default is read text, so you don't even need the "r" unless you are using some other modifier like "b" or "+".

Comment: As for being explicit, a counter argument that I follow is that people should always know the default (if they are not sure, there should be a handy doc string) so you shouldn't parameterize something unless its _different_ than the default. Seeing `open('foo". "r")` makes my brain have to think, wait a second... why not just the default?